# In Out bound Email. Is this possible to remove component link if it is present on any page of your website?

Tags: outbound-email

In out bound Email I want to remove component link which is not resolved. Means which is not present on any page of your web site. I am able to remove component link from web if it is not resolved but not from email. I have implicit tracking on email page. So format should be XHTML. I don't want to redirect unresolved link to resolve.html page. Please help me.

Comment: On the surface it seems like you would just edit the Page Template and remove the part where it outputs the Component Link as a link. Does that not work for you? Is something else outputting the link?

Comment: Or even just remove or update the link in the Component -- or actually publish the item that's linked to.

Comment: Peter, This is happening because we can not use tridion:href and tridion:textonfail in email anchor because this is not taken by the email. For Email I use <a href="component.ID" >link</a> and for web we use <a tridion:href="component.ID" tridion:textonfail="False">link</a>. It works well in web. But I am not able to remove the link from email if component not resolved.

Comment: I did'nt understand your first comment.

Comment: You are correct that you cannot remove the link from an e-mail if it doesn't resolve. E-mail doesn't work like that, unfortunately. Which is why it first redirects to the website and then it will resolve it there. If it cannot, it will fall back to redirecting to a page of your choice. Nobody wants that, so you should make sure that links in your e-mail belong there and that the content they point to is published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to e-mail, there is no way to dynamically render Component Links in the e-mail itself. So the link instead is redirected to the website, where the link is then resolved. If it cannot be resolved, the visitor is redirected to an error page instead.

Because of this, you should ensure that any links you put in a Mailing can actually be resolved. You do this by either making sure the linked Component is published to the website, or removing the link in your Component, or by not outputting the link in your Component Template.